# Expandable Tree Menu with parent links inactive

Tags: 7, routes, navigation

In Drupal 7 I am trying to have a tree menu that the parent items expand/contract on click, but I do not want the parent items to be a page link. I have tried DHTML Module and it does not work how I expected it to work.

I am even willing to try a solution where the tree menu is fully expanded but the Parent Item is not a link, just static text.

Suggestions?

Comment: Try [nice menu](http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus).Nice Menus enables drop-down/right/left expandable menus

Comment: I've tried this, however, i want it to be stacked and not a flyout sub-menu. And still need to make the parent item static text